# How to make a Public website access to other PC within the LAN?

Tags: vs-web-site-project

I have a Huawei HG256s router (local LAN IP 192.168.1.1) which is configured to with a local IP 192.168.1.10 as DMZ to my WD MybookLive. I also have another buffalo NAS which has IP of 192.168.1.11. I setup a web server on the MybookLive and using the public IP available from the Huawei router, I can visit my website. I am able to access both MybookLive and Buffalo NAD within my WIFI LAN, but it does not work via internet. My question is how can I make a website that will allow me to access to my buffalo NAS from internet? Any advice will be helpful. Thanks you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you set up a port forwarding.
That can be done in the router menu.
Afterwards you can access the service running on the port via the public IP on that specified port.